# Approve or reject the post during review task

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, rollbacks, posts

I've noticed that while reviewing the post is not locked for the concrete reviewer and someone other reviewer can make an action such as approve or reject.

If such thing happens when you want to make your own action the message appears that says the post is already approved or already rejected giving a link to the post.

I can use the link to edit the post. But it seems worthless as I don't know how to rollback the previous revision. Is there any possibility to do so?

Why after using that link and redirecting to the post to make changes cannot return back to continue review?

Why such a post doesn't count for the reviewer task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can use the link to edit the post. But it seems worthless as I don't
>   know how to rollback the previous revision. Is there any possibility
>   to do so?

It is possible.
Click on timestamp in "Edited 4 secs ago". That opens the revision history as shown below:

[image]

I have commented in red text below. You can click on rollback there to revert to that particular revision.

> Why after using that link and redirecting to the post to make changes
>   cannot return back to continue review?

Because on clicking the link, you were redirected to that particular post. You will have to go to review page again to continue reviewing other posts.

> Why such a post doesn't count for the reviewer task?

Because each suggested edit needs only 3 approves or 3 rejects to be reviewed. In this case, the edit was already suggested before you clicked on submit of your improve, or you clicked on reject. So that won't count in your completed reviews.

Comment: What is the best practice for the reviewer to handle such case if it "won't count in the completed reviews"?

Comment: @RomanC I think, at that time reviewer should just make the necessary corrections using rollbacks and not worry about review.

Comment: What if the necessary corrections not required, and worry about not a review but worry about count the completed reviews.

Comment: @RomanC, Its all about our timings. If 4 reviewers started to review same post at same time. And say, one of them took a little more time than other 3 reviewers. The edit was already approved. And then 4th reviewer clicked on Approve. In that case also, completed review count won't be increased

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: @RomanC Sadly, I don't know the reasons. But I think its fair enough as that edit was already proceeded

Comment: Correct! What if I just skip the case?

Comment: @RomanC, you skip the case, that means you neither approved, rejected nor improved. Means you didn't review it at all. So that wouldn't make any increment in count

Comment: No, skip the case that is the post is already approved, and I need save my time *to be able* continue with other posts.

Comment: @RomanC, If the post is already approved/Rejected before you open the list, then it won't appear to you for reviewing

Comment: No, you don't understand the post is appeared and it approved by other reviewer when I was viewing it and it appears not countable when I press the Approve or Reject button, what to do to save my time and proceed?

Comment: @RomanC, Yes, you can use "Skip" option then.

Comment: Correct! Thank you, I have solved my problem.